# TinyMCE v4.1 multiple textboxes with different settings

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have searched a lot without finding a working answer.

I have three texarea in my ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_EN" class="mceEN" CssClass="mceEN" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_IT" class="mceIT" CssClass="mceIT" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_FR" class="mceFR" CssClass="mceFR" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>
```

I need to make the first textarea's toolbar in English, the second in Italian and the third in French.

How is it possible?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not work for me BUT I've found a "solution".

The problem is only with TinyMCE v4.x.

Using versions 3.x (3.5.11 in my case) all worked fine...

I don't know if it is a bug or a different behaviour...

the final working javascript code is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                mode: "textareas",
                editor_selector: "mceFR",
                theme: "advanced",
                language: "fr",
                ...
});
tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                mode: "textareas",
                editor_selector: "mceEN",
                theme: "advanced",
                language: "en",
                ...
});
tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                mode: "textareas",
                editor_selector: "mceIT",
                theme: "advanced",
                language: "it",
                ...
});
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:-

1. Download one or more languages [from here](http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/)
2. Unpack files into your tinymce/langs folder
3. In your `tinymce.init({...})` config, set the language option to whatever language you want, example:
4. `language : 'sv_SE',`
5. And you are done, load up TinyMCE and check the new language

Now you can add all your three languages for different textareas.

Did you see this:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:language](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3alanguage)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer,

yes i downloaded all the languages I needed. Here is part of JS code:
// for english
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        editor_selector: "mceEN",
        ...
    });
// for italian
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        editor_selector: "mceIT",
        language: "it",
        ...
    });
// for french
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        editor_selector: "mceEN",
        language: "fr_FR",
        ...
    });

The problem is that ALL toolbar are in French (the last initialization).

Comment: Yes.. Because you have added the same selector textarea.  Try passing  selector : '.mceEN' and also for other classes

Answer (score 0):

You can setup multiple instances of TinyMCE on a page by using different values for the `selector` property

With this html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_EN" class="mceEN" CssClass="mceEN" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_IT" class="mceIT" CssClass="mceIT" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Content_FR" class="mceFR" CssClass="mceFR" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="270"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can have the following javascript

```
tinymce.init({
    selector   : '#TextBox_Content_EN'
});

tinymce.init({
    selector   : '#TextBox_Content_IT'
});

tinymce.init({
    selector   : '#TextBox_Content_FR'
});
```